# What is a probability heat map?

Tags: data-visualization, heatmap

What is a probability heat map? In general, what is a heat map? Many papers on neural networks use probability heat maps for visualisation. My understanding is that heat maps are plots of (typically continuous) values where there is a one-one correspondence between the range of values displayed and a spectrum of colours. Probability heat map is similar with different colours indicating regions of different probability. Is this intuition correct?

For example, see the paper [Stacked Hourglass Networks for Human Pose Estimation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06937) which uses probability heatmaps for different human keypoints (although it doesn't explicitly use the term *probability* heatmap).

Comment: This question could benefit from an example.

Comment: @Sycorax added one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map), you get that

"A heat map (or heatmap) is a graphical representation of data where the individual values contained in a matrix are represented as colors."

There is nothing more really... As an example, consider the following multivariate normal data.

```
library(mvtnorm)

Sigma <- matrix(0, nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
Sigma[1:3,4:5] <- .25
Sigma[1:3,6:8] <- .1
Sigma[4:5,6:8] <- .2

Sigma <- Sigma + t(Sigma)

Sigma[1:3,1:3] <- .5
Sigma[4:5,4:5] <- .75
Sigma[6:8,6:8] <- .35

diag(Sigma) <- 1

X <- rmvnorm(30, rep(0,8), Sigma)

par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
image(t(cor(X)[8:1,]))
```

[image]

The image produced actually uses `R`'s color palette known as `heat.colors` by default. The "heat" term comes from the colors used I guess.

A probability heat map (seems to be, from this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363252/probabilty-heatmap-in-ggplot?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the same kind of technique applied to probability distributions instead of correlation matrices.

In particular, if you have $(X_1,X_2)$ and want to predict $Y \in \{0,1\}$, then you could color your 2D space (at point (x_1,x_2)) using $P(Y = 1 | X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2)$, with the color range $[0,1]$.